# Tool to get dual problem from any linear optimization problem (.lp)

Tags: linear-programming, duality

Is there a tool that reads any linear optimization problem (for example an .lp or .mps file), converts it to the dual problem and prints the dual problem?

Answer (score 8):

I recommend having a look at the most recent developments around [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/). They have developed two interesting packages this year:

- [MathOptFormat.jl](https://github.com/odow/MathOptFormat.jl/), that allows to import/export optimization problem in MPS, LP, CBF, etc...
- [Dualization.jl](https://github.com/guilhermebodin/Dualization.jl), that allows to dualize automatically any optimization problem in conic form

You can find [here a Julia script](https://gist.github.com/frapac/86fd965a252012ba1d4ce3b39dee0390) that takes as input a MPS file and output the dual problem in a LP file.

However, I get some problems with MathOptFormat, as this package is not yet able to import LP files... Still a work in progress I guess!

Comment: For me, the Julia script does not work (see my comment in the Gist).

Answer (score 6):

The [link](https://cbom.atozmath.com/CBOM/Simplex.aspx?q=pd&q1=3%605%60MIN%60z%60x1%2Cx2%2Cx3%603%2C-2%2C4%603%2C5%2C4%3B6%2C1%2C3%3B7%2C-2%2C-1%3B1%2C-2%2C5%3B4%2C7%2C-2%60%3E%3D%2C%3E%3D%2C%3C%3D%2C%3E%3D%2C%3E%3D%607%2C4%2C10%2C3%2C2%60%60D%60false%60true%60false%60true%60false%60false%60true&do=1#PrevPart) includes an online converter from primal to dual linear programs. The downside is you need to input all the coefficients and variables into the pre-defined form on the webpage.

Comment: Here is another similar calculator: http://www.mathstools.com/section/main/simplex_online_calculator#.XZT_T0ZKhPZ - but the one you posted seems much easier to use

Comment: The link from the answer also accepts the problem pasted in a text format. Which text format is this? It's not lp or mps.